# How to convert JS keyed object into keyed array while skipping undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, key-value

How to convert this JS object:

```
users = {
  1: { id: 1, name: "..." },
  2: { id: 2, name: "..." },
  // 3 is missing
  4: { id: 4, name: "..." },
  ...
}
```

into an array:

```
usersArray = [
  1: { id: 1, name: "..." },
  2: { id: 2, name: "..." },
  // 3 is missing -- I do not want undefined here
  4: { id: 4, name: "..." },
  ...
]
```

The key is that I do not want undefined, blank spaces, the key must be the object Id. The reason I do not want blanks/undefined entries is because I use `vue.js` and I am pretty sure it would not iterate over an array with undefined values in `v-for`.

Something like: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-best-practices-for-complex-objects/10143/2 but without the additional array storing just ids.

Is this possible?

Comment: `// 3 is missing -- I do not want undefined here` so you want to redefine numbers, that after 2 now comes 4? You can not have both in one datastructure: items mapped by ids which have gaps and a list without gaps.

Comment: @Thomas you can actually have a key like 'abc' if you wanted on an array... so non sequential numbers should be no big deal.

Comment: it's not about wether you can or can't have rantom keys on an Array. you're asking for these three things at the same time: a list without gaps, the rownumber should equal the id of the item in that row and the id's have gaps. You can have any 2 of these 3 things in one object, but not all 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.values()`

```js
const users = {
  1: { id: 1, name: "..." },
  2: { id: 2, name: "..." },
  4: { id: 4, name: "..." },
};
console.log(Object.values(users))
```

Comment: The array is not keyed?

Comment: @ColtonScottie Please add the expected output.

Comment: I did, see my question.

Comment: @ColtonScottie Oh yeah. That is incorrect javascript array. You can't have `keys` in an array.

Comment: @ColtonScottie What do you want to see when `userArray[2]` is accessed?

Comment: The same element that was accessed when `users[2]` was accessed. And arrays CAN be keyed.

Comment: @ColtonScottie So what is the point to convert that object to array. Object is fine for that purpose.

Comment: I cannot call all the methods like `.length`, `.filter`, `.map` on the object. It making my life difficult! My code was originally written to use array, but it makes sense to use object in the `vuex` store for quick lookups, and arrays in the consuming components.

Comment: then do this and rebuild you object when you no longer need an array

Comment: @ColtonScottie I think `Object.values` will work for you here. You can use `filter()` etc. on it and if you want to the the original `id` then its present in form if `id` property of the object.   Secondly you are saying _"3 is missing -- I do not want undefined here"_. You can't skip any index in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sparse array with missing indices by assigning the object to an array. As you see, `forEach` or `map` does not visit sparse items.

```js
var users = { 1: { id: 1, name: "..." }, 2: { id: 2, name: "..." }, 4: { id: 4, name: "..." } },
    array = Object.assign([], users);

array.forEach((o, i) => console.log(i, o));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: But unfortunatly the length of `array` is 5 even though the number of items to iterate over is 3. This would cause havoc if I used `v-if` to hide things based on length

Comment: Essentially I want a dictionary but with the power of array functions, like sort, filter etc.

Comment: that is not possible out of the box.